# How to find the Bertrand curve of a given curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Given a regular curve $\Gamma_1$ whose natural parametric equation is that
$$\Gamma_1:\quad 
\begin{cases} 
\displaystyle x=\frac{s}{2}-\sin\frac{s}{2}\\ 
\displaystyle y=1-\cos\frac{s}{2}\\ 
\displaystyle z=4\sin\frac{s}{4}\\ 
\end{cases}$$
How to find a regular curve $\Gamma_2$ such that $(\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2)$ become Bertrand pair of curves?

Where the fixed angle between two tangent vectors to these two curves is $\frac{\pi}{3}$ at each corresponding point.

**Note:** In case you're not familiar with these topics, you'll find links to more information in the Reference of this post.

**Reference:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves

Comment: You might start by working Exercise 20 on p. 21 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). In particular, if $\beta = \alpha + rN$ is the Bertrand mate of $\alpha$, you should find that $1-r\kappa=r\tau\cot\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent vectors. This particular curve leads to pretty messy $\kappa$ and $\tau$, so have fun!

Comment: Update: Because someone else inquired about this question, I have worked on it a bit more. The problem seems quite wrong. Certainly using the angle $\pi/3$ we do not get that $\tau\cot\theta + \kappa$ is constant.